# Menu Dropdown do bootstrap não funciona

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e estou utilizando o menu dropdown do bootstrap mas não funciona

Minha `<head></head>`

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
```

```
  </head>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="body-wrap" >

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="azul">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <div class="conteudo"><li><a href="#">PAGINA PRINCIPAL</a></li></div> 
          <div class="conteudo"> <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li></div>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <div class="conteudo"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRODUTOS <b class="caret"></b></a></div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bermudas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

 </div>
```

JS

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
 }, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
 });
```

Comment: Porque estar a criar um elemento `script` passando como atributo um arquivo `CSS` ?

Comment: eu mudei Wéllingthon tinha colocado o código errado

Comment: Veja o que esta retornando no `console`

Comment: bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Esta usando `Linux` ? Isso ai tem a ver com permissões. `Forbidden` quer dizer `Proibido` cheque as permissões do arquivo.

Comment: Estou usando windows

Comment: Mesmo assim, verifique as permissões acesso do diretório e arquivo, seu código está bagunçado, você esta importando 2 vezes o `bootstrap` veja, esta usando um `cdn` e importando local. Não vai dar certo, ou um ou outro.

Comment: então tenho que configurar a segurança  do bootstrao.min.js ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67212/discussion-between-wellingthon-m-de-souza-and-user1999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom a varias duplicações de importação em seu código, é necessário fazer um limpa, tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas alterações.

1. O problema por estar retornando `403 - Forbidden` é porque a *URL*

   ```
   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
   ```

   Foi atualizada e passou a ser

   ```
   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
   ```
2. Você esta importando o *jQuery*, *Bootstrap* e o *Font Awesome* usando *CDN*, então não há necessidade de importar local, removi as linhas:

   ```
   <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
   ```

Ficando assim seu código.

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- OUTRAS BIBLIOTECAS -->
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-wrap" >

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="azul">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <div class="conteudo"><li><a href="#">PAGINA PRINCIPAL</a></li></div> 
          <div class="conteudo"> <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li></div>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <div class="conteudo"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRODUTOS <b class="caret"></b></a></div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bermudas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

 </div>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo obrigado Wéllingthon